# Button в MaterialDrawer

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. Использую библиотеку [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) для отображения бокового выдвижного меню. Требуется в `header` меню добавить кнопку. Пробовал так: добавил кнопку в **drawer_header.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/header"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" >
    </ImageView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="plus"
        android:id="@+id/button_size_plus"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Затем как обычно объявляю кнопку в `MainActivity`: `Button button_size_plus;` и затем инициализирую её в `onCreate`: `button_size_plus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_size_plus);`. Далее создаю слушатель `setOnClickListener` для кнопки и тут при запуске приложения получаю краш с NPE, значит видимо неправильно инициализировал кнопку и не смог "достучаться" до неё в MaterialDrawer. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это правильно сделать. Приложу пример инициализации одного поля (строчки) в MaterialDrawer и создание самого объекта:

```
PrimaryDrawerItem item1 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(22).withName(R.string.about_name).withSelectable(false).withIcon(R.drawable.about);

        result = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withToolbar(toolbar)
                .withHeader(R.layout.drawer_header)
                .withTranslucentStatusBar(true)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggleAnimated(true)
                .addDrawerItems(
                        item1
                )
                .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {

                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                })
                .build();
```

**UPD**

```
View viewInHeader = result.getDrawerLayout().findViewById(R.id.button_size_plus);
        viewInHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "header", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вбиваем в гугл

> mikepenz/MaterialDrawer get header view

2. идём по первой же [ссылке на issues](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/issues/665) привёденной вами же ссылке на gitHub
3. читаем её, смотрим пример из README библиотеки и понимаем, что искать вьюху надо в объекте, возвращаемом при создании дровера как-то так:

   ```
   Drawer result = new DrawerBuilder()
       .withActivity(this)
       ...
       .build();
   View viewInHeader = result.getHeader().findViewById(...);
   ```

Comment: Обновил первый пост. Сделал все как Вы указали, все равно крашится на строке `viewInHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {` с `NullPointerException`

Comment: Попробуйте так: result.getHeader().findViewById(...);

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! Очень помогли!