# Доступ к элементам меню в Toolbar

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. Имеется Toolbar с отображаемыми элементами от меню.

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/button_size_plus"
        android:title="@string/text_plus"
        android:icon="@drawable/button_size_plus"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/button_size_minus"
        android:title="@string/text_minus"
        android:icon="@drawable/button_size_minus"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

Инициализация:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить доступ из кода для смены иконок итемов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще меню можно получить как-то так:

`toolbar.getMenu()`

но лучше завести boolean переменные, от коих будет зависеть назначение иконок в `onPrepareOptionMenu()` и в нужный момент надо будет лишь поменять значения вышеозначенных переменных и вызвать перерисовку меню так:

`supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()`

переопределяем метод

```
boolean someBoolean;

/* Called whenever we call supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    Log.d("LOG", "onPrepareOptionsMenu called");
    MenuItem item = menu.findItemById(...);
    if(someBoolean){//set some icon}
    else{//set another icon}

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

далее, где-то в коде меняем

```
someBoolean = !someBoolean;
supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Comment: Спасибо. Не могли бы Вы привести пример данной реализации? Что-то не получается сделать метод...

Comment: @Pollux, немного кода добавил

Comment: Большое спасибо! Попробую

Comment: Загляните пожалуйста [сюда](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/555665/button-%D0%B2-materialdrawer) Очень похожая проблема.