# Как в Action Bar сделать видимость иконки меню, зависимой от флага в checkbox?

Tags: android, checkbox, menu, actionbar

Приветствую. Не давно начал изучать андроид и вот возник вопрос(в заголовке). 
Буду очень благодарен за помощь, так как в обилии классов и методов в SDK еще сильно "плаваю".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { //вызывается при вызове меню


    MenuItem action_mail = menu.findItem(R.id.action_item4);
    if (chb2.isChecked()){
        action_mail.setVisible(true);
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    }else{
        action_mail.setVisible(false);
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.groupID, chb1.isChecked());
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Переопределите onPrepareOptionsMenu

   ```
   /** Called whenever we call supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() */
   @Override
   public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
   {
       MenuItem  itt = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_share);

       //здесь по условию меняйте меню

       return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
   }
   ```
2. В момент изменения условия перерисуйте меню вызвав

   ```
   supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()
   ```

---

Вот тут ещё можно посмотреть:

[Доступ к элементам меню в Toolbar](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/555747/17609)

Comment: Я попробовал по вашему совету. Может что не так понял, но эффект такой, что видимость иконки не меняется, пока я на меню не жмакну и он перерисует только тогда.

Comment: @Gerltsx, это `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();` надо вызывать не там где у вас, а там где обрабатывается изменение нужного флага. Если у вас чекБокс - то в слушателе изменения его чекнутости

Comment: спасибо за помощЬ)) Получилось)